# Placing li one above another and on removing last li every li's will come down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to stack one li over another li and when i remove bottom li then every other li's above that will come down automatically.
I tried this http://www.think360apps.co.in/evdt/game/  (the left side 5 icons )but when i remove the bottom li then it coming something like this shown below:[Images attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I4Y6.png)

Can someone help me to bring the top four li's to bottom automatically when i remove last li?

Comment: Show us some code. What've you tried so far?

Comment: This is the code that i have written, now i want that when i remove last li tag then every other li tag shifts to bottom automatically. Please help
https://jsfiddle.net/amz7hbj6/

Comment: Posting the jsfiddle could help, but posting the code adding it to the question itself is for sure a better way to expose your problem. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put your ul into a div with `bottom: #px;` replacing # with the correct position. Instead of specifying height, specify max-height. This div should then be automatically shrunk as your li items are removed.

```css
.playerInfo {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
.playerStatus {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    max-height: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playerInfo">
  <div class="playerStatus">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the code that i have written, now i want that when i remove last li tag then every other li tag shifts to bottom automatically. Please help jsfiddle.net/amz7hbj6